# How to find only SD card movable applications on the market?

Tags: google-play-store, sd-card, app2sd

As I do not have more free space on my HTC Desire, I am interested only in applications which can be moved to the SD card. How to find them on the market (via web interface, or on the device, does not matter) ?

Answer (score 7):

The Market doesn't support this (or any search filters aside from price and "safe search", really) on either the website or the native app. It has been [requested a handful of times](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!searchin/android-market/sd%2420card%2420search) on the Google support forums, but never really received much of a response.

[AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) **does** support this, however ([example search](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=clock&filter=app2sd)), so you could use that to search and then install from the Market if you wanted. Inconvenient, but at the moment there's not much else you can do about that.