# Which app specific prevents moving to external storage?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, app2sd

Subject. I'm not asking what I will lose if I move app, but rather about **how system detects if app is "movable" or not and enables/disables corresponding button in "App Info" activity accordingly**. Hope I made myself clear, if now - please comment and suggest better terminology.

Comment: Your answer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Comment: @Firelord, thanks, that's exactly what I asked about. I wonder if I should delete this Q...

Comment: I would say you self answer it now. That said, see if another same question has already been asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out if an app can be moved to the SD card before I install it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24635/how-do-i-find-out-if-an-app-can-be-moved-to-the-sd-card-before-i-install-it)

Comment: Your [answer is here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/106125/16575). All those items, when an app needs one of them, must be listed in the app's `Manifest` – so it's easy for the system to "detect".

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is related to [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) and behavior in question controlled by application manifest, specifically, by [`android:installLocation`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) attribute (**NB**: by default system assumes `internalOnly`).